# Open an Application after minimized to dock with shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dock

Is it possible to open a minimized Application in dock with a shortcut? Or maybe something like: Open last minimized Application in dock with shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

1. Navigate to the minimized Application by doing
   <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. While **still holding** <kbd>Command</kbd> press <kbd>Option</kbd>
3. Release both keys. Or just <kbd>Command</kbd> for that matter.

Comment: Yeah, the option button works well in this case :)